# Transform a solution vector of PDE into a piecewise linear function - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pde

I know that when I use the PDE toolbox in Matlab to solve a PDE the result is a vector, which represents the values of the function in each vertex of the mesh.

> Is there a command in the PDE toolbox such that we could transform the vector solution into a piecewise linear function on the domain of definition, so that we could be able to use it like u(x,y) to find directly the approximate value in (x,y)?

Comment: Not directly related, but you might like [Chebfun](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about such function. But your solution is defined on a structured rectangular grid. If you simply need to interpolate data on a 2D rectangular grid, you can use `interp2` for that. If your grid is made of triangles, use `TriScatteredInterp`. If you want to use different interpolation (e.g., FEM), you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: or, of course, `interp1` if it's 1-dimensional, or `interpn` for N-dimensional interpolation.